# What did Hare want to give to Shu at the moment of her death?

Tags: guilty-crown

At the point where Hare got shot, after healing Shu, she says, "Shu... I'll give you my..." but dies before finishing her sentence. What did she want to say to Shu?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as user4670 said, she would probably say, "Shu, I'll give you my heart," that is the most practical answer.

However, since the sentence does go unfinished, it's really up to the imagination of the watcher what she would say, even if the answer can be quite obvious.

Another few possibilities are "...my soul." as well as "...my love." However these are probably the least likely answers of the three possibilities, despite all three representing a similar meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I think she wanted to say: "Shu I give you my heart". After all she did entrust Shu with her void before, and she wanted to show that her heart belonged to him, because she loved him.